# Click function on list shouldn't affect nested ul

Tags: jquery, list, nested

My problem is that I only want Header 1 and Header 2 to call the click function. If i click on List item 1.1 etc I want nothing to happen. As it is now, clicking on any list item will call the event.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#nav li ul").hide(); 
    $("ul#nav li").click(function() {
        $("ul#nav li").removeClass("current"); 
        $(this).addClass("current"); 
        $("ul#nav li ul").slideUp('fast'); 
        $(this).find("ul").slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
    <ul id="nav">  
        <li><a href="#">Header 1</a>
        <ul>
           <li>List item 1.1</li>
           <li>List item 1.2</li>
           <li>List item 1.3</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
       <li><a href="#">Header 2</a>
       <ul>
           <li>List item 2.1</li>
           <li>List item 2.2</li>
           <li>List item 2.3</li>
       </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

I have looked through a couple of similar questions and answers but they did not quite help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$( nav ).delegate( 'li', 'click', function () {   
    if ( !$( this ).parent().is( nav ) ) { return false; }  
    $( this ).siblings( '.' + clss ).removeClass( clss ).children( 'ul' ).slideUp( 'fast' );
    $( this ).addClass( clss ).children( 'ul' ).slideDown( 'fast' )
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WsZdJ/4/

Comment: Ok, i see the point  +1. Although if they click on an already open one it should slide it up, i would think.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder No, because `$( this ).siblings( '.' + clss )` cannot select the clicked LI element. The `slideUp` executes only if one of the siblings of the clicked LI have the class set.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `>` to get only the child li's and not all decedent li's.

```
<ul id="nav">  
    <li><a href="#">Header 1</a></li>
    <ul>
       <li>List item 1.1</li>
       <li>List item 1.2</li>
       <li>List item 1.3</li>
    </ul>

   <li><a href="#">Header 2</a></li>
   <ul>
       <li>List item 2.1</li>
       <li>List item 2.2</li>
       <li>List item 2.3</li>
   </ul>

</ul>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#nav ul").hide(); 

    $("ul#nav > li").click(function(e) {
        if( $(this).hasClass('current') )
        {
          $(this).removeClass("current"); 
          $("ul#nav ul").slideUp('fast');
        }
        else 
        {  
          $('.current').removeClass('.current');             
          $(this).addClass("current");         
          $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });

});
```

Comment: This won't work - even though the code will select only the top most `<li>`s as the other `<li>`s are inside the top level `<li>`s clicking on them will still fire the `click` event. See - http://jsfiddle.net/WsZdJ/

Comment: @ipr101 That's because the outer LI contains the inner LI's. An `event.target` check is required here...

Comment: Could I get an example? I tried the first given answer and as someone stated it didn't work.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder Because there is only one handler (the LI's share the same handler). It is better to bind the common handler only once (on the common ancestor), then to bind it to every LI element. "Bind only once" is better than "bind multiple times".

Comment: Thanks a lot Interstellar_Coder!